# how to count number of lines of a specific entry under a specific pattern using awk?

Tags: bash, awk

I have a text file with a pattern that looks like the following

```
Sample1
Feature 1
A
B
C
Feature 2
A
G
H
L
Sample2
Feature 1
A
M
W
Feature 2
P
L
```

I'm trying to count how many entries are for each feature in each sample. So my desired output should look something like this:

```
Sample1
Feature 1: 3
Feature 2: 4

Sample2
Feature 1: 3
Feature 2: 2
```

I tried using the following awk command:

```
$ awk '{if(/^\Feature/){n=$0;}else{l[n]++}}
       END{for(n in l){print n" : "l[n]}}' inputfile.txt > result.txt
```

But it gave me the following output

```
Feature 1: 6
Feature 2: 6
```

So I was wondering if someone can help me in modifying this command to get the desired output or suggest for me another command?
(P.S the original file contains hundreds of samples and around 94 features)

Comment: Why did you put a backslash before `Feature` in `if(/^\Feature/)`? Btw, never use the letter `l` as a variable name is it looks far too much like the number `1` and so obfuscates your code.

Comment: @EdMorton I don't have much experience in awk commands and this command was suggested in a previous post. Thanks for the note about the letter "l", i will avoid using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this `awk`:

```
awk '/^Sample/{printf "%s%s",(c?c"\n":""),$0;c=0;next}
     /^Feature/{printf "%s\n%s: ",(c?c:""),$0;c=0;next}
     {c++}
     END{print c}' file
```

The script increment the counter `c` only for lines that doesn't start with `Sample` or `Feature`.

If one of the 2 keywords are found, the counter is printed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and explanation! The command worked very well!

Answer (score 0):

This `awk` may also work:

```
awk '/^Sample/ {
   for (i in a)
      print i ": " a[i]
   print
   delete a
   next
}
/^Feature/ {
   f = $0
   next
}
{
   ++a[f]
}
END {
   for (i in a) 
      print i ": " a[i]
}' file
```

```
Sample1
Feature 1: 3
Feature 2: 4
Sample2
Feature 1: 3
Feature 2: 2
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS = ": " }
/Sample/  { prtFeat(); print (NR>1 ? ORS : "") $0; next }
/Feature/ { prtFeat(); name=$0; next }
{ ++cnt }
END { prtFeat() }
function prtFeat() {
    if (cnt) {
        print name, cnt
        cnt = 0
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
Sample1
Feature 1: 3
Feature 2: 4

Sample2
Feature 1: 3
Feature 2: 2
```